# Is there a reason why e.target and an htmlelement cannot be compared?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am trying out working with dropdown menus, and I was thinking about making a template for the dropdowns so that I can easily recreate them without any additional Javascript. However, in one of my if loops, an event.target and another element are always returning that they are different when they aren't. It doesn't make any sense, since they are the same element (proved by the console) and should be returning true. Here is the code:

```js
const _$$ = (q) => document.getElementsByClassName(q);
let dropdowns = _$$('dropdown');
if (dropdowns[0]) {
  for (let dropdown of dropdowns) {
    let title = dropdown.children[0],
      options;
    title.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
    title.addEventListener('focus', function() {
      options = Array.from(dropdown.children).slice(1, dropdown.children.length);
      for (let option of options) {
        option.style.display = 'block';
        option.setAttribute('tabindex', options.indexOf(option) + 1);
        option.style.top = `${title.offsetHeight+options.indexOf(option)*title.offsetHeight}px`;
        option.style.padding = window.getComputedStyle(title, null).getPropertyValue('padding');
      }
      document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(title);
        if (e.target !== dropdown || e.target !== title) {
          for (let option of options) {
            if (e.target !== option) {
              option.style.display = 'none';
            }
          }
        }
      }, false);
    }, false);
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-title {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  color: blue;
  background: white;
  width: fit-content;
}

.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-title {
  outline: none;
}

.dropdown-option {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown --top-dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-title" tabindex="0">Dropdown</div>
  <div class="dropdown-option" tabindex="1" style="display: none; top: 31px; padding: 5px 8px;">Dropdown Option</div>
  <div class="dropdown-option" tabindex="2" style="display: none; top: 62px; padding: 5px 8px;">Dropdown Option</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `e.target` and `option` are the same element. However, in the if loop where it says `if (e.target !== dropdown || e.target !== option) {...}` it is always saying they are different elements and removing the dropdown options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `e.target !== dropdown || e.target !== title` should be changed to `e.target !== dropdown && e.target !== title`. The reason for that is when `e.target` equals `title`, it necessarily doesn't equal `dropdown` and vice versa (when `e.target` is `dropdown`, and when the condition is or (`||`) the expression is always `true`.

```js
const _$$ = (q) => document.getElementsByClassName(q);
let dropdowns = _$$('dropdown');
if (dropdowns[0]) {
  for (let dropdown of dropdowns) {
    let title = dropdown.children[0],
      options;
    title.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
    title.addEventListener('focus', function() {
      options = Array.from(dropdown.children).slice(1, dropdown.children.length);
      for (let option of options) {
        option.style.display = 'block';
        option.setAttribute('tabindex', options.indexOf(option) + 1);
        option.style.top = `${title.offsetHeight+options.indexOf(option)*title.offsetHeight}px`;
        option.style.padding = window.getComputedStyle(title, null).getPropertyValue('padding');
      }
      document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target !== dropdown && e.target !== title) {
          for (let option of options) {
            if (e.target !== option) {
              option.style.display = 'none';
            }
          }
        }
      }, false);
    }, false);
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-title {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  color: blue;
  background: white;
  width: fit-content;
}

.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-title {
  outline: none;
}

.dropdown-option {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown --top-dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-title" tabindex="0">Dropdown</div>
  <div class="dropdown-option" tabindex="1" style="display: none; top: 31px; padding: 5px 8px;">Dropdown Option</div>
  <div class="dropdown-option" tabindex="2" style="display: none; top: 62px; padding: 5px 8px;">Dropdown Option</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't really understand though... does the language assume the first expression is true if you include the `||` operator?

Comment: Nope - when a logical expression is or (`||`) if any part of the expression is `true`, the entire expression is `true`. In your case `e.target` can only equals to `dropdown` or to `title`. Since your expression is "not equal to dropdown" or "not equal to title", you'll always have a part which is `true` -> the entire expression is `true`.